# Using C# Windows service

Tags: windows, service, parameters

I would like to create a utility to automatically copy files from one folder to another folder. 
•   The target and destination folder will be specified as a parameter
•   The file type in (i.e. “*.csv” or “*.txt”) will also be specified as a parameter

How to pass parameters to windows service.. Please reply ..

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer if it helped or accept it if it worked for you.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Set your service to be a web service on some obscure port. Use a REST api (or whatever you like) to put a json/xml (or use get query strings if you like to) post to the service with directory, extension, and whatever else you might need.

The service has the data and can do its thing.   You can also define other apis the web server can respond to which can stop the copy process or report status on ongoing copies (10 of 15 files copied, etc).   You can enhance and augment it however you like.